# QGIS 3.26.3 3D View rotation is choppy

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, 3d

When I try to rotate a view in 3D it's very choppy.  Any idea why this might be?
[Video of Choppy 3D view](https://youtu.be/ByMDuVEXJ6c)
This is the output from the animation, but it's exactly the same as when I try to rotate with the mouse.  It is all default settings in relation to 3D besides the terrain being set

- I've reset the User interface settings to default
- It does the same when it's just a flat terrain
  Any idea how to fix this or what is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I had added the elevation layer in the Project Settings - Terrain.  I think my problems began when the project was opened with this setting set.  However, it didn't improve after I removed it from the Project settings

I don't know why, but the fix was to install 3.28.0, and from the 3D View Panel, I set the Elevation layer again, and it worked.